# Regular expression ends with specific character but ignore it

Tags: javascript, regex

```
console.log("1h2m3s".match(/\d+h/i));
```

The code results in `1h` but I want just the number it self. I could cut off the end, but I don't want to do that. How do I just isolate just the number part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead instead which checks for the `h` component:

```js
console.log("1h2m3s".match(/\d+(?=h)/i));
```